# PHP não atualiza dados de ficheiro .txt

Tags: php

Estou fazendo um contador de visualizações de uma aplicação, que são armazenadas num ficheiro .txt. No entanto o ficheiro fica sempre a 0. Se o ficheiro não existir, este é criado, com o valor `0` escrito. No entanto este nunca é actualizado sempre que a app é visualizada por um outro utilizador. O código encontra-se no meu `AppController` no `afterFilter`. Sempre que testo se o ficheiro é actualizado limpo os dados da cache, para a sessão deixar de existir. Qual é o problema do código?

**Código**

```
    public function afterFilter(){
    $counter = APP."webroot/counter/counter.txt";

 // verifica se o ficheiro existe. se não existe cria um com o valor 0.
    if (!file_exists($counter)) {
        $f = fopen($counter, "w") or die("o ficheiro não pode ser aberto");
        fwrite($f,"0");
        fclose($f);
    }

 // lê o valor do ficheiro
    $f = fopen($counter,"r") or die("o ficheiro não pode ser aberto");;
    $counterVal = fread($f, filesize($counter));
    fclose($f);

 //verifica se o visitante foi contado, actualiza o ficheiro.
    if(!isset($_SESSION['hasVisited'])){
        $_SESSION['hasVisited']="yes";
        $counterVal++;
        $f = fopen($counter, "w") or die("o ficheiro não pode ser aberto");;
        fwrite($f, $counterVal);
        fclose($f);
    }
    $counterVal = str_pad($counterVal, 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

}
```

Comment: Você pode tentar utilizar `file_get_content` e `file_put_contents` do PHP se seu servidor permitir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu código funcionou corretamente aqui em meus testes...

```php
session_name("TESTESPHP-CotadorVisitas");
session_start();

$counter = __DIR__."/counter.txt";

// verifica se o ficheiro existe. se não existe cria um com o valor 0.
if (!file_exists($counter)) {
    $f = fopen($counter, "w") or die("o ficheiro não pode ser aberto");
    fwrite($f,"0");
    fclose($f);
}

// lê o valor do ficheiro
$f = fopen($counter,"r") or die("o ficheiro não pode ser aberto");;
$counterVal = fread($f, filesize($counter));
fclose($f);

//verifica se o visitante foi contado, actualiza o ficheiro.
if(!isset($_SESSION['hasVisited'])){
    $_SESSION['hasVisited']="yes";
    $counterVal++;
    $f = fopen($counter, "w") or die("o ficheiro não pode ser aberto");;
    fwrite($f, $counterVal);
    fclose($f);
}
$counterVal = str_pad($counterVal, 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

echo $counterVal;
```

o erro no seu pode ser a falta de uma / em:

```
   $counter = APP."/webroot/counter/counter.txt";
```

Comment: Estranho não ter recebido nenhum aviso quanto a isso. Anteriormente tive alguns problemas em ligar o ficheiro mas deixei de receber avisos depois de o colocar como está na minha questão. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.